# FastText difference between saving directly and saving after build_vocab and training with epochs

Tags: nlp, word2vec, fasttext

I've been building FastText model and saving as following:

```
model = FastText(#some parameters)
model.build_vocab(corpus_strings)
model.train(corpus_iterable=corpus_strings, total_examples=len(corpus_strings), epochs=model.epochs)
model.save(filename)
```

After a while, I tried to save without training because I've seen that someone using FastText in that way:

```
model = FastText(corpus_strings, #some parameters)
model.save(filename)
```

I've seen that the generated vectors by those 2 models are not same for same strings. I'm thinking that it could be because of epochs but is there any other impact that comes from build_vocab and train?

On the other hand, I want also to know that what is the difference between those 2 ways, which one should better in which case?

The vector generated by 2 different models (first has been built by build_vocab, train and save and the second saved directly after calling model = FastText(#some parameters)) are not. I was expecting same vectors. And I want to know why it is the case.

Answer (score 0):

From the `.build_vocab()`, it looks like you may be using the Gensim Python FastText implementation... but that `FastText` class **doesn't* have a `.save_file()` method, so it's a bit unclear what library or implementation you're using.

Note that if in Gensim your `#some parameters` include a corpus, the initial contruction of the model will **also** do training. (In such a case, there's no need to later call `.build_vocab()` or `.train()`.)

However, most generally: the training process uses enough inherent randomization, and is spread over many threads whose order-of-operation can vary from run to run, that repeated runs with the exact same parameters & data **will not** reliably create the exact same vectors.

Instead, the only expectation is that, with sufficient training data & good parameters, that the vectors from repeated runs should be about-as-useful for downstram applications. All the vectors could be arbitrarily far from a prior run, but the neighborhoods of nearest-words, and general dirctions, should be roughly-as-reliable. (The nearest-neighbors for words will be largely the same; the use of the vectors as input to other processes will be about as beneficial.)

There's more discussion of this in the Gensim project FAQ, Question 11:

https://github.com/RARE-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Recipes-&-FAQ#q11-ive-trained-my-word2vec--doc2vec--etc-model-repeatedly-using-the-exact-same-text-corpus-but-the-vectors-are-different-each-time-is-there-a-bug-or-have-i-made-a-mistake-2vec-training-non-determinism

Comment: Yes, I use Gensim Python FastText and you are right, I was not using .save_file(), I made a mistake when I was changing filename. I edited my code.

In the first implemantation I don't use corpus as a parameter but the second has corpus as a parameter. I edited it.

I tried to find the cosine similarity of some sentences, first model found similarities [0.9-1] for every pairs while second model found [0.3-1] (logical but the reason is not clear for me). 

What are good parameters for *2vec methods and how to find them?

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by "first model found similarities [0.9-1] for every pairs while second model found [0.3-1]". Even with what I've pointed out about run-to-run-differences, if 2 models are both trained with the exact same parameters & data, the pairwise cosine-similarities between words should be roughly similar, and the range of all such pairwise values should be similar. If not, something else must be going wrong or done differently between the 2 models.

Comment: It's reasonable to begin with the class/method defaults for parameters, or parameters that are successfully used or advocated in other published work that tackles similar data/tasks. Then, try variantions once you have a good way to evaluate each run as being better or worse for your goals. But, if your data or goals are very different from that in examples you're following, you may need to make larger parameter adjustments. If you're having problems with specific parameters & data, post more details about which params, the size/kind of data, & how the results don't match hopes.